# Identifying one number between a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
A = [[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9, 2]]
```

I want to compare all the values in the nested lists ([2, 3], ..., [2, 3], ..., [9, 2]) and extract the number that appears once, in this case 9, if you find a number that only appears in one list in a list. That is the answer for that block i.e:

```
A = [[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9]]
```

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: He wants to remove duplicates (2 is a dup), but "lists between the list" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: and specifically, which duplicate does he want to remove? The last occurrence?

Comment: In this example, what would be the expected output?

Comment: There are also two occurrences of `3`, but neither of them are removed.  Definitely needs some clarification.

Comment: @F.J: I was wondering about that as well. This question is not clear at all.

Comment: if you find a number that only appears in one list in a list. That is the answer for that block, i don't want to remove the occurrences, i want to get the number that is different to the others, that's why the 9 is kept

Comment: Then did you mean to leave out the last `2` from the output list?

Comment: [What are you *really* trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messy, hard to read list comprehension, but the other answers are **so long**!

Include a list member if it's an integer, or if it's a sublist that only has members that occur more than once in the combined list of all sublists. Otherwise, that is, if it is a sublist with members that are unique in all sublists, include only the unique members for that sublist.

```
>>> A = [[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9, 2]]
>>> L = [y for x in A if type(x) == list for y in x]
>>>> [x if (type(x) == int) else x if all([L.count(y) > 1 for y in x]) \
      else [y for y in x if L.count(y) == 1] for x in A]

[[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract values that appear in only one sublist, no matter how many times they appear in that sublist, you could do this:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_answer(x):
    my_list = []

    for ele in x:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            my_list.extend(list(set(ele)))

    countz = Counter(my_list)
    return [k for k,v in countz.iteritems() if v == 1]
```

Result:

```
>>> get_answer([[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9, 9]])
[9]
>>> get_answer([[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9, 2]])
[9]
```

If you wanted to extract a number that appears only in one sublist and only once in that sublist, that is it only shows up once among all elements of all sublists, you would change
this line:

```
my_list.extend(list(set(ele)))
```

to

```
my_list.extend(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import collections

A = [[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9, 2]]
B = []
occurences = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for element in A:
    if type(element) is list:
        B.append(element)
for sublist in B:
    for number in sublist:
        occurences[number] += 1
for sublist in B:
    for number in sublist:
        if occurences[number] == 1:
            del sublist[:]
            sublist.append(number)
print(A)
```

Result:

```
[[2, 3], 5, 7, 8, [2, 3], 1, [9]]
```